Questions about Alfred Noyes' Midnight Express #3: What is Mortimer's "escape"?
I have this(these) question(s) regarding Alfred Noyes' "Midnight Express"
Because I have about ten questions regarding this, I will post each individually.
I don't want to give any exerpt from the story because it is so intricately interconnected that it is best to give it a quick read. But still, here's a relevant excerpt:

But when the story came to the wayside cottage, for the third time, a deeper suspicion began to dawn upon him, slowly, fearfully, inevitably – Although there was no escape, he could at least try to grasp more clearly the details of the strange circle, the fearful wheel, in which he was moving.
There was nothing new about the details. They had been there all the time; but he had not grasped their significance. That was all. The strange and dreadful being that had led him up the crooked stair – who and what was That?
The story mentioned something that had escaped him. The strange host, who had given him shelter, was about his own height. Could it be that he also – And was this why the face was hidden?
At the very moment when he asked himself that question he heard the click of the key in the locked door.
The strange host was entering – moving toward him from behind – casting a grotesque shadow, larger than human, on the white walls in the guttering candlelight.
It was there, seated on the other side of the fire, facing him. With a horrible nonchalance, as a woman might prepare to remove a veil, it raised its hands to unwind the cerecloth from its face. He knew to whom it would belong. But would it dead or living?
There was no way out but one. As Mortimer plunged forward and seized the tormentor by the throat, his own throat was gripped with the same brutal force. The echoes of their strangled cry were indistinguishable; and when the last confused sounds died out together, the stillness of the room was so deep that you might have heard – the ticking of the old grandfather clock, and the long-drawn rhythmical ‘ah’ of the sea, on a distant coast, thirty-eight years ago.

Here's the third question:

Why did Mortimer kill the old(or dead?) man who gave him shelter?

For escape? Why did he think that was the only escape? Furthermore escape from what?? His subconscious? How does he escape if he kills him? Is the older man his doppelganger or future self? So by killing the future self, isn't he killing himself(as is indicated in the story)??
I have read the story so many times but still I can't make the head and tail out of the story. These are the questions lingering in my mind ever since I read the story. I found no satisfactory answers in the internet.
Thanks in advance!

You ask: "escape from what?"
Consider the following passage:

But when the story came to the wayside cottage, for the third time, a deeper suspicion began to dawn upon him, slowly, fearfully, inevitably – Although there was no escape, he could at least try to grasp more clearly the details of the strange circle, the fearful wheel, in which he was moving.

Why does he come to the wayside cottage "for the third time"? The story in the book apparently is repeating itself ... it comes to the wayside cottage again, and again, and again.
More evidence for this is the fact that the last line of the story

It was a battered old book, bound in red buckram…

is the same as the first line. So presumably, the story continues by starting over at the beginning, in an endless loop.
This is speculation, but possibly, if Mortimer hadn't killed his doppelgänger, he would have been taken back to himself as a child of twelve — and possibly this has already happened. There is some evidence for this from the passage immediately following Mortimer's death (my italics):

... when the last confused sounds died out together, the stillness of the room was so deep that you might have heard – the ticking of the old grandfather clock, and the long-drawn rhythmical ‘ah’ of the sea, on a distant coast, thirty-eight years ago.

This is almost exactly the same as the description of the sounds in Mortimer's childhood room at the beginning of the story.
As a child, he may have blocked the memory of this time loop, which is why the book is so disturbing to him and why he has to pin page 50 closed.
So this time loop (which Mortimer had completely forgotten about) is presumably what he wants to escape from.
Why did Mortimer kill his host? To escape from the time loop that he is trapped in. And he does escape, by dying, although it seems likely that this wasn't how he intended to escape — presumably he thought (if indeed he was thinking at all) that if he killed his host, his host couldn't send him back to his childhood.

Thanks! This cleared many things up but, this raises the question whether the old man is his doppelganger or a harbinger of the repeating future. By killing his harbinger, he may have restarted the whole story, but that logic does not work well with doppelganger interpretation. Furthermore, is he Mortimer's future self? And I don't understand how killing/suiciding(?) restarts the story. Furthermore, those sounds of his previous home implies(?) that he somehow teleported(?) there and also a hint of the recurrence. These are actually my next questions from this same passage, which I'm uploading.

@FKcosθ: I'm not sure that Mortimer killing himself restarts the time loop — maybe it ends the time loop. It's not clear (to me, at least) from the story.
